# Threadsafe function wrapper for pthread api functions

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have a C library for Linux (*.so) that is supposed to wrap the pthread functions so I can build a small lock contention measurement tool. Currently it employs lazy evaluation and the functions look roughly like this:

```
int pthread_mutex_lock (pthread_mutex_t * mutex )
{
    static int ( *pthread_mutex_lock_internal ) ( pthread_mutex_t * mutex ) = NULL;

    if (pthread_mutex_lock_internal == NULL)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock_internal = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "pthread_mutex_lock");

        if (real_pthread_mutex_lock == NULL)
        {
            abort();
        }
    }

    return (pthread_mutex_lock_internal(mutex));
}
```

The questions I have now are:

- Is this implementation thread safe? It is intended for a program with 150+ threads. I saw some people using double-checked locking for their wrappers.
- Could it be more efficient?

Regards

Comment: Could you please explain what problem does this function solve? Why don't you call pthread_lock directly?

Comment: I will add more code to it. This is only the prototype with basic function pointer initialization.